# How to sort heading and underlying content as a unit?

Tags: sorting, unix

I have content in the form that a heading is given then under that content is written.

I need to sort the headings but the underlying content will be sorted independently not with the heading as a unit.

One method that I could do is grep all the headings sort those on fly and paste the heading and no of lines below that into a new file.

But I want some efficient way to do it. Please suggest some method. The sample of content is given below (Currency is heading and below given are serial no for that currency)

```
C01
====
892341231,786754321,1234567

C05
====
78675433432, 1245673234
```

Comment: Please show the desired output. What are the 'serial numbers' — numbers off example bank notes?  How big can the lists of serial numbers get? Are they split over multiple lines?  Most probably, you need to format the input data so that each currency and all its serial numbers are on a single line, sort that list, and then retransform the single line data into multiple lines again.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks Jonathan for replying , 

I need the output in sorted format according to the headings like in above it is already sorted in ascending order  
yes the data below heading is in a single line

Comment: And the data includes the line of equals signs, and the blank line between currencies?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes

Answer (score 1):

The Unix `sort` command deals with single lines of data.  One option, as outlined in a comment, is to convert the data to a single line per currency, use `sort`, and then disentangle the composite line:

```
sed -e 'N;N;N;s/\n/ /g' data | sort | perl -p -e 's/ (=+) /\n$1\n/; s/ $/\n/;'
```

`sed` was proving recalcitrant about putting newlines into the string, so I used `perl` instead.  Of course, if you're using `perl` at all, you can do the whole job in `perl`. This is the verbose version, a fairly direct transliteration of the `sed` and `sort` parts, except that there's no need to remove the newlines, which simplifies the printing after the sorting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @currencies;

while (<>)
{
    my $l2 = <>;
    my $l3 = <>;
    my $l4 = <>;
    push @currencies, "$_$l2$l3$l4";
}

print foreach (sort @currencies);
```

Given the input file:

```
C01
====
892341231,786754321,1234567

C05
====
78675433432,1245673234

C02
====
444341231,333754321,2224567
```

both scripts produce the output:

```
C01
====
892341231,786754321,1234567

C02
====
444341231,333754321,2224567

C05
====
78675433432,1245673234
```

This is Perl, so There's More Than One Way To Do It (TMTOWTDI) and the other ways use less brute force and are less fragile than reading 4 lines at a time.  For example, you can set the line delimiter to `""` to force paragraph mode, so each 'line' of input is a paragraph, separated by one or more blank lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "";
my @currencies = <>;
print foreach (sort @currencies);
```

Of course, even that's a bit verbose. We do away with the explicit array, and therefore we don't need `use strict;`, and we can just about afford to reduce it to:

```
local $/ = "";
print foreach (sort <>);
```

Or you can add a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
local $/ = "";
print foreach (sort <>);
```